# Appending a single string in an array to a list item (li) using file upload?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I am trying to upload 10 files at once and create a unordered list of the names of all of those file. It works fine until i try to upload more than one file.

The issue: I am currently getting back all strings of an array under 1 `li` but I wish to print out each of the file uploads in their own li, because as you will see in my code, I am also appending a checkbox, which would mean each file needs their own li. I dont understand why it is not printing each file to its own li. My guess would be that it takes in 1 file "upload" input (that can and may hold more than 1 file ) and acts like it is a single upload ( despite more than 1 file being uploaded ).

Here is my code.

```
        var fileList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
          fileList.push(e.target.files[i].name);
        }

        const formatedArray = fileList.map(x => {
          return x.replace(".pdf", "");
        });

        console.log(fileList);
        console.log(formatedArray);

        ul = document.createElement("ul");

        document.getElementById("uList").appendChild(ul);

        formatedArray.forEach(function(item) {
          let li = document.createElement("li");
          ul.appendChild(li);

          var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
          checkbox.type = "checkbox";
          checkbox.value = 1;
          checkbox.name = "todo[]";

          li.appendChild(checkbox);

          li.innerHTML += formatedArray;
        });
      };

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: I think this line is a problm =>           li.innerHTML += formatedArray;
it should be           li.innerHTML += item;

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: can you please mark answer and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var fileList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
          fileList.push(e.target.files[i].name);
        }

```
    const formatedArray = fileList.map(x => {
      return x.replace(".pdf", "");
    });

    console.log(fileList);
    console.log(formatedArray);

    ul = document.createElement("ul");

    document.getElementById("uList").appendChild(ul);

    formatedArray.forEach(function(item) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      ul.appendChild(li);

      var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.value = 1;
      checkbox.name = "todo[]";

      li.appendChild(checkbox);

      li.innerHTML += item;
    });
  };
```